# Can you return 0 when stopping an upstart service which is already stopped?

Tags: upstart, services, chef

I have a custom upstart service which I'm trying to automate via Chef. The chef flow is like this:
- Create /etc/init/myservice.conf, notify restart myservice (if conf file changes)
- Start myservice

The Chef service restart is actually carried out as `/sbin/stop` and `/sbin/start`
So, if my service isn't already running, the restart fails saying that `/sbin/stop myservice returned 1`

Is there a way I can return 0 on `/sbin/stop myservice` if the service is already in a stopped state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with tomcat and chef, use this:

> /sbin/status tomcat_7 | grep -q "stop/waiting" || /sbin/stop tomcat_7

For start:

> /sbin/status tomcat_7 | grep -q "start/running" || /sbin/start
>   tomcat_7